# LaTeX not citing properly

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib

I am trying to figure out why my reference is not being cited properly and it's been cut off. It looks like that:

[image]

The reference should look like that-> "(Harvard T.H. Chan School of Public Health (2012)". Since I am new to LaTeX, I would appreciate any advice! Thank you!
P.S.: I use `natbib` for bibliography management

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

main.tex file:

```
\documentclass [oneside, a4paper, openany]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel} % Use British english for hyphenation etc
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Auto add Bibliography etc to Table of Contents
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % Use BibTeX for bibliography management
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Create hyperlinks within text
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature Review}
\label{Chapter:Literature-Review}

The next section will discuss the consequences of SB and the suggested amount of physical activity per day \citep{harvardthchanschoolofpublichealth2012}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.tex file:

```
@misc{harvardthchanschoolofpublichealth2012,
author = "Harvard TH Chan School of Public Health",
organization = "The Nutrition Source",
title = "Measuring physical activity",
url = "https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/mets-activity-table/",
urldate = "2016-11-09",
year = "2012",
month = "09",
day = "18"
}
```

Comment: Put curly brackets around the author.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the suggestion but it does not work. The result is the same :/

Comment: Can you post a mininal working example so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Johannes_B This is a link to a small version of the code that can be excecuted-> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7MaiC_Cj3XsdXVIdjE2TlRTUU0?usp=sharing

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, agree with you. I added the code to the question. :)

Comment: I can see the whole *author* (though it isn't an author, nevermind). Did you recompile using latex and bibtex and latex  and bibtex and latex (takes a bit to update).

Comment: @Johannes_B That's strange. I am using the online ShareLatex editor. I just downloaded the source code and compiled locally with TexWorks (pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex compiler) and the result is the same :/ Are you using the curly brackets as you suggested?

Comment: Are you using **two** levels of curly brackets?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was it! That worked! I was using single brackets. Thank you very much! Please add your answer as a solution to my problem. That was simple. Why it requires the usage of brackets to display the whole author?

Comment: it is treating `of Public Health` like `van Beethoven` as a compound surname and dropping  the given names of `Harvard TH Chan School` the extra braces `{Harvard TH Chan School of Public Health}` make the whole thing a single "word"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments